# GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery exception on migration from SDN 4.0 to SDN 4.1.RC1

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am in the process of migrating my application to use SDN 4.1.0.RC1 but have encountered a few issues after trying to boot the application. I have made the necessary configuration changes to correctly use the HTTPDriver to my remote server (localhost:7474) and when booting the application I get the following error with one of my repositories while attempting to load the spring context.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

This is the vanilia repository that seems to be crying

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

  @Query("MATCH (u:User) where u.authId = {authId} return u limit 1")
  User findOneByAuthId(@Param("authId") Long authId);

}
```

**EDIT**

It looks like it could be a disconnect between the version of spring data and spring data neo4j.

The GraphQueryLookupStrategy in question...

```
/*
 * Copyright (c)  [2011-2016] "Pivotal Software, Inc." / "Neo Technology" / "Graph Aware Ltd."
 *
 * This product is licensed to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this product except in compliance with the License.
 *
 * This product may include a number of subcomponents with
 * separate copyright notices and license terms. Your use of the source
 * code for these subcomponents is subject to the terms and
 * conditions of the subcomponent's license, as noted in the LICENSE file.
 *
 */

package org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.NamedQueries;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.RepositoryQuery;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * @author Mark Angrish
 * @author Luanne Misquitta
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 */
public class GraphQueryLookupStrategy implements QueryLookupStrategy {

    private final Session session;

    public GraphQueryLookupStrategy(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    /* 
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy#resolveQuery(java.lang.reflect.Method, org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata, org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectionFactory, org.springframework.data.repository.core.NamedQueries)
     */
    @Override
    public RepositoryQuery resolveQuery(Method method, RepositoryMetadata metadata, ProjectionFactory factory,
        NamedQueries namedQueries) {
        return new GraphQueryMethod(method, metadata, factory, session).createQuery();
    }
}
```

It appears the QueryLookupStrategy I have is expecting a method `RepositoryQuery resolveQuery(Method method, RepositoryMetadata metadata, NamedQueries namedQueries);` to be implemented which clearly it is not. I assume this is now a dependency issue and will investigate further with the version of Spring Data I need to be compliant with SDN

```
/*
 * Copyright 2008-2010 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.data.repository.query;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.data.repository.core.NamedQueries;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * Strategy interface for which way to lookup {@link RepositoryQuery}s.
 * 
 * @author Oliver Gierke
 */
public interface QueryLookupStrategy {

    public static enum Key {

        CREATE, USE_DECLARED_QUERY, CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND;

        /**
         * Returns a strategy key from the given XML value.
         * 
         * @param xml
         * @return a strategy key from the given XML value
         */
        public static Key create(String xml) {

            if (!StringUtils.hasText(xml)) {
                return null;
            }

            return valueOf(xml.toUpperCase(Locale.US).replace("-", "_"));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Resolves a {@link RepositoryQuery} from the given {@link QueryMethod} that can be executed afterwards.
     * 
     * @param method
     * @param metadata
     * @param namedQueries
     * @return
     */
    RepositoryQuery resolveQuery(Method method, RepositoryMetadata metadata, NamedQueries namedQueries);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so if you run into this issue there is a pretty straight forward way to resolve it. Please see the documentation at http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/ . This exception was caused by version conflicts with the spring data commons module. The interface that neo4j implements in version 4.1.0.RC1 has changed and thus this exception is thrown.

To Resolve use the Spring Data release train BOM and set it to release Hopper-RC1 . Since I use gradle the instructions are below but you can also find them at the link above.

Relevant build script simplified...

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.4.0.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-releasetrain:Hopper-RC1'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:4.1.0.RC1'
}repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}
```

Cheers,

Steve

Comment: This worked.  By now you can use Hopper-RELEASE and this still works.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Holycowzer's answer for Maven users. Add the following line to your builds POM.xml. Note that this is will sit outside of your main `<dependencies />` tag set.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
        <version>Hopper-SR1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I noticed some imports broke while doing this, simply add them explicitly as dependencies in your POM and everything should work as expected.