# Invocation of init method failed when I add a query in a repository

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm trying the spring-data-neo4j in a project. I defined my domain object but I've got problems with the repository usage.

Below the code of my repository interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
    public User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Easy, isn't it ? :)

But when I launch my spring project (a REST service), I got those exceptions:

```
23:13:23.833 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at hello.Hello2Kt.main(Hello2.kt:18)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryMetadata;Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/NamedQueries;)Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/RepositoryQuery;
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GraphRepositoryFactoryBean.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52143', transport: 'socket'
23:13:23.836 [main] INFO  o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar, file:/Users/batman/IdeaProjects/Sphynx/target/classes/, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.6/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.0.1-2/kotlin-stdlib-1.0.1-2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-runtime/1.0.1-2/kotlin-runtime-1.0.1-2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.3.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-data-neo4j-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-core/2.0.1/neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-api/2.0.1/neo4j-ogm-api-2.0.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-compiler/2.0.1/neo4j-ogm-compiler-2.0.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm-http-driver/2.0.1/neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.0.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/1.1.0/neo4j-ogm-1.1.0.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j/2.2.2/neo4j-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-kernel/2.2.2/neo4j-kernel-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-primitive-collections/2.2.2/neo4j-primitive-collections-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-unsafe/2.2.2/neo4j-unsafe-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-io/2.2.2/neo4j-io-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-csv/2.2.2/neo4j-csv-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-lucene-index/2.2.2/neo4j-lucene-index-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/3.6.2/lucene-core-3.6.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/2.2.2/neo4j-graph-algo-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-udc/2.2.2/neo4j-udc-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-graph-matching/2.2.2/neo4j-graph-matching-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher/2.2.2/neo4j-cypher-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/scala-library-2.10.5.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.5/scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9/2.0.4/neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.4.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0/2.0.4/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.4.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1/2.1.8/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.8.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2/2.2.2/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.10/1.1.7/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.7/parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.4/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-jmx/2.2.2/neo4j-jmx-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-consistency-check/2.2.2/neo4j-consistency-check-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-server/2.2.2/neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/server-api/2.2.2/server-api-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/3rdparty/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.2.r612/jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/app/neo4j-browser/2.2.2/neo4j-browser-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-access/1.1.7/logback-access-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/janino/janino/2.7.8/janino-2.7.8.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/janino/commons-compiler/2.7.8/commons-compiler-2.7.8.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-server-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-http-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-util-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-io-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-webapp-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-xml-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-servlet-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.2.16.v20160414/jetty-security-9.2.16.v20160414.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.18.1/jersey-server-1.18.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.18.1/jersey-core-1.18.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-servlet/1.18.1/jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.10/commons-configuration-1.10.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.2/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.13/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/rrd4j/rrd4j/2.2/rrd4j-2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/rhino-1.7R4.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/140/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-multipart/1.18.1/jersey-multipart-1.18.1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/mimepull/mimepull/1.9.3/mimepull-1.9.3.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-shell/2.2.2/neo4j-shell-2.2.2.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline/0.9.94_1/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar, file:/Users/batman/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar, file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar]
```

That is my dependencies (from pom.xml):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

As you can see, I'm using a release version of the neo4j spring data integration (4.1.1.RELEASE).

For your information, if I don't declare any query function in the repository interface, the spring application starts without error.

Answer (score 1):

could possibly be caused by a version conflict. could you try using the spring data without the version tags.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>

    </dependency>
```

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36410303/839979)

Comment: Yes, SDN 4.1.1 is part of the Hopper-SR1 release train

Comment: @austin Remove the version tags is not a good idea because I back to a 3.4.x version of the module. But, your link brings me the answer by adding the Hopper-SR1 dependency.

Comment: @Luanne I think the reference documentation of spring-data-neo4j should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to austin and the link he provided me, I've succeeded to launch my application with a repository.

I've added those lines below in my pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Hopper-SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```